# Inserting a picture into the text of the theorem (using \newtheorem)

Tags: wrap, newtheorem, wrapfig

I need the text *to wrap around the image*. I tried to include \usepackage{wrapfig} and code was like this.

```
\begin{theorem}
  \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{image.png}
    \end{center}
  \end{wrapfigure}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt lacus non metus ornare, in scelerisque dolor maximus. Suspendisse elit odio, venenatis congue turpis et, posuere vulputate sapien. Curabitur diam sapien, dapibus accumsan molestie eget, feugiat non felis. Sed in neque ac nisl molestie gravida sagittis pretium diam. Sed eget porttitor ligula, eget feugiat quam. Curabitur fermentum elit ligula, vel egestas elit condimentum id. Nullam sed tempus mi.

\end{problem}
```

But the output was like that

```
TEXT
.
.
.
Theorem 
*image*
```

How should I rewrite my code to achieve needed result